# How to interrupt a read operation using BufferedReader (Java)?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Hello although I read a lot of other answeres I do not understand how to close BufferedReader without sending input. This is the blocking part of my program:

```
public class AuctionClientUserListener extends Thread {

    private PrintWriter out;
    private BufferedReader stdIn;
    private int udpPort;
    private boolean running = true;
    private boolean listening = true;

    // needs server connection out
    public AuctionClientUserListener(BufferedReader stdIn,PrintWriter out,int udpPort) {
        this.stdIn = stdIn;
        this.out = out;
    }

    public void run() {
        String fromUser;

        while(true) {
            if(!listening) {
                break;
            }
            try {

                fromUser = stdIn.readLine(); // BLOCKS

                if (fromUser != null) {
                        System.out.println("Me: " + fromUser);

                        // check if to send udp port
                        String[] spinput = fromUser.split(" ");
                        if(spinput[0].equals("!login")) {
                            fromUser+=" "+udpPort;
                        }

                        out.println(fromUser);

                        if(fromUser.equals("!end")) {
                            listening = false;
                        }
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                listening = false;
            }
        }
        running = false;
    }

    public boolean running() {
        return running;
    }

    public void endListening() {

        this.listening =  false;
    }
}
```

When I call "endListening()" from the main thread, the program terminates - but NOT BEFORE the user inputs anything. I want to the program to terminate instantly - how to intterupt this BufferdReader (is created like BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)) )?

I tried to call stdIn.close() and also thread.interrupt() on this Thread in the main Thread, but it ist not working. I also tried to close the InputStreamReader in the main Thread.

Comment: try using a Scanner instead of a BufferedReader.

Comment: Is there a possibility to solve it with Buffered Reader?

Comment: The people are being distracted by the title. I would advise a title like "Interrupt a read operation" or "Unblock a read operation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check to see [if there's data available](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) before calling `BufferedReader.readLine()`, i.e.

```
while(true) {
    if (!listening) break;
    if (System.in.available() > 0) {
        try {
            fromUser = stdIn.readLine();
            // etc.
```

Comment: If there is say, one character `a` in the inputsream, your check will pass but the `readLine` will still block waiting for the endline character.

Comment: Great, that solved the problem. Although I still wonder if there is another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `thread.interrupt` to signal the thread to interrupt its process. Be ready to catch an `InterruptedException` launched by the thread.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Answer (score 0):

i think u can close your BufferedReader using stdIn.close();